# Error when using Calculated Column in a measure

Tags: dax

I'm a beginner in Dax language, can you help me to solve that problem? 
I want to use that calculated column

```
Date Sortie Assiciation =
IF (
YEAR ( [DATE_SORTIE_ASSOCIATION] ) = YEAR ( TODAY () )
&& MONTH ( [DATE_SORTIE_ASSOCIATION] ) = MONTH ( TODAY () )
&& DAY ( [DATE_SORTIE_ASSOCIATION] ) = DAY ( TODAY () );
BLANK ();
[DATE_SORTIE_ASSOCIATION]
)
```

into a measure , this column returns the right results in Visual Studio but when I use it in my measure I got This Error : The column referenced by the Expression 'Effectif par Poste[ Date Sortie Assiciation]' does not contains any data, because it should be recalculated or refreshed.

Thank you.

Comment: Is `[DATE_SORTIE_ASSOCIATION]` a measure? If it's a column, I'd expect the table name to precede it.

Comment: it's a calculated column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I needed to process the measure groupe in SSMS because the deploy does not take account the changes of data in column calculated.
thank you.